# How to match for optional pattern in Lua?

Tags: lua

I am trying to learn how to match for optional pattern in Lua.

```lua
local text = '10+'
local start_index, end_index, value = string.find(text, "%d+(%+)")
print(start_index, end_index, value)
```

Using this as an example, I want `+` to be optional and still return the index of number when `+` doesn't exist in that string.

I tried this pattern but it will returns `nil, nil, nil`

```lua
local text = '10+'
local start_index, end_index, value = string.find(text, "%d+(%+)?")
print(start_index, end_index, value)
```

How can I make `+` optional correctly in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `?` into the capture!

```
local text = '10+'
local start_index, end_index, value = string.find(text, "%d+(%+?)")
print(start_index, end_index, value)
```

Comment: Note: this only works for this case because it's a single character in the group.